# How to separate boxplots in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset, boxplot, continuous

I have to plot a boxplot for the PM2.5 levels when the rain > 0 for 12 noon.
I’ve used the code:

```
boxplot(PM2.5~RAIN, data=subset(dat, RAIN > 0 & hour == 12), range = 0)
```

But it comes up with several boxplots (e.g. one boxplot for 0.1 mm rain, another for 0.2 mm rain)

Any help with separating these boxplots would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to create a constant in the data and then use that on the right-hand side.

```
dat$CONSTANT <- 0
boxplot(PM2.5~CONSTANT, data=subset(dat, RAIN > 0 & hour == 12), range = 0)
```

Another option is to create a subset first.

```
with(subset(dat, RAIN > 0 & hour == 12),
    boxplot(PM2.5, range = 0) )
```